# PROBLEMAS AL USAR INNERHTML JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

Buen dia, no he podido realizar la carga de una fucnion ya que me marca error en el innerHTML

.php

```
var cell0= row.insertCell(0);
                             var folio = data['datos_tabla'][index]['descripcion'];

                            cell0.innerHTML ='<td bgcolor="blue" align="center"><a href="#" title="Elegir concepto" onclick="javascript:return conceptos_erp()" >'+folio+'</a></td>';
```

Y en el JS segun yo tengo todo bien espero me ayuden aqui les dejo el

:JS

```
function conceptos_erp()
{
    document.getElementById("ayuda").innerHTML="";
    var det=$("#ayuda").dialog({modal: true});
    det.html('<div align="center">Cargando Datos ...<images src="img/loading.gif"/></div>');
    det.dialog({position: "top"});
    det.load("conceptos_erp.php");
    det.dialog(
    {
        title:'Catalogo de Conceptos',
        buttons:{
                        "Cerrar": function()
                        {
                            //$(this).dialog("close");
                            det.dialog('close');
                            $("#mail").focus();
                        }
                 },
        width:530,
        height:400
    });
    det.dialog('open');

}
```

ERROR:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me pueden ayudar y orientar, saludos

Comment: En el error aparece `+=`, pero en tu codigo solo aparece `=`

Comment: A es que ya le quite y probe sin el + y sigue marcando el mismo error

Comment: Es posible que te tire ese error porque no existe un elemento con el id `id="ayuda"`.

Comment: Que tipo de elemento es? por que si es input la propiedad a modificar es value si es un div u otra etiqueta distinta de un input debes utilizar innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

para ver el error debes poner el puntero sobre el circulo rojo con la equis, si te sale el siguiente error quiere decir que en el DOM no existe ningun elemento con ese ID

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que es lo que buscas al ejecutar:

```js
document.getElementById("ayuda")
```

Por eso deber de seleccionar un ID existente.

Espero esto te ayude a resolver el problema!